# Factorisation of $a^3-b^3+8c^3+6abc$

Tags: factoring

I came across this question which states " Factorise this : $a^3-b^3+8c^3-6abc$". This confused me and I'm not even sure if this is factorable however It'll be cool to see how it's factorised, if it can be.

Comment: The title is inconsistent with the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonnhard got the right idea, but made one small typo. The correct answer is $$a^3-b^3+8c^3+6abc=(2c+a-b)\left(a^2+b^2+4c^2+ab-2ac+2bc\right).$$
The expression $a^3-b^3+8c^3-6abc$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Please address *which* of the two versions of the question you are answering: the expression as given in the title, or the one given in the body of the post?  They are not the same expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using identity $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$

Which gives
$$a^3-b^3+8c^3-6abc = (a-b+2c)(a^2+b^2+4c^2+ab+2bc-2ca)$$

Comment: You've made a small sign error: your factorisation is for $a^3-b^3+8c^3+6abc$. But yes, this is essentially how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: One factor is $$2c+a-b$$
Multiply out $$(2c+a-b)(a^2+ab-2ac+b^2+2bc+4c^2)$$

Comment: No, it isn't. This thing is not factorisable.

Comment: it is factorisable, and i want my point $-1$ back

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2c%2Ba-b)(a%5E2%2Bab-2ac%2Bb%5E2%2B2ac%2B4c%5E2)
damn, you are stubborn, didn't even care to check

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard identity:
\begin{align}x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz&=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)\\&=\tfrac12(x+y+z)\bigl((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\bigr)\end{align}